# MD5 Hash of ISO-8859-1 string in Java

Tags: java, utf-8, md5, iso-8859-1

I'm implementing an interface for digital payment service called [Suomen Verkkomaksut](http://www.verkkomaksut.fi/index.php?id=24). The information about the payment is sent to them via HTML form. To ensure that no one messes with the information during the transfer a MD5 hash is calculated at both ends with a special key that is not sent to them.

My problem is that for some reason they seem to decide that the incoming data is encoded with ISO-8859-1 and not UTF-8. The hash that I sent to them is calculated with UTF-8 strings so it differs from the hash that they calculate.

I tried this with following code:

```
String prehash = "6pKF4jkv97zmqBJ3ZL8gUw5DfT2NMQ|13466|123456||Testitilaus|EUR|http://www.esimerkki.fi/success|http://www.esimerkki.fi/cancel|http://www.esimerkki.fi/notify|5.1|fi_FI|0412345678|0412345678|esimerkki@esimerkki.fi|Matti|Meikäläinen||Testikatu 1|40500|Jyväskylä|FI|1|2|Tuote #101|101|1|10.00|22.00|0|1|Tuote #202|202|2|8.50|22.00|0|1";
String prehashIso = new String(prehash.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "ISO-8859-1");

String hash = Crypt.md5sum(prehash).toUpperCase(); 
String hashIso = Crypt.md5sum(prehashIso).toUpperCase();
```

Unfortunately both hashes are identical with value C83CF67455AF10913D54252737F30E21. The correct value for this example case is 975816A41B9EB79B18B3B4526569640E according to Suomen Verkkomaksut's documentation.

Is there a way to calculate MD5 hash in Java with ISO-8859-1 strings?

**UPDATE:** While waiting answer from Suomen Verkkomaksut, I found an alternative way to make the hash. Michael Borgwardt corrected my understanding of String and encodings and I looked for a way to make the hash from byte[].

Apache Commons is an excellent source of libraries and I found their DigestUtils class which has a md5hex function which takes byte[] input and returns a 32 character hex string.

For some reason this still doesn't work. Both of these return the same value:

```
DigestUtils.md5Hex(prehash.getBytes());
DigestUtils.md5Hex(prehash.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"));
```

Comment: Never use first form of `getBytes()` if you want to get a predictable result. It uses the default encoding of your system. You been from Finland it is most likely that your default encoding is 'ISO-8859-1', so both calls will produce the same results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java has a standard java.security.MessageDigest class, for calculating different hashes.

Here is the sample code

```
include java.security.MessageDigest;

// Exception handling not shown

String prehash = ...

final byte[] prehashBytes= prehash.getBytes( "iso-8859-1" );

System.out.println( prehash.length( ) );
System.out.println( prehashBytes.length );

final MessageDigest digester = MessageDigest.getInstance( "MD5" );

digester.update( prehashBytes );

final byte[] digest = digester.digest( );

final StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();

for ( final byte b : digest ) {
    final int intByte = 0xFF & b;

    if ( intByte < 10 )
    {
        hexString.append( "0" );
    }

    hexString.append(
        Integer.toHexString( intByte )
    );
}

System.out.println( hexString.toString( ).toUpperCase( ) );
```

Unfortunately for you it produces the same "C83CF67455AF10913D54252737F30E21" hash.  So, I guess your Crypto class is exonerated. I specifically added the `prehash` and `prehashBytes` length printouts to verify that indeed 'ISO-8859-1' is used. In this case both are 328.

When I did `presash.getBytes( "utf-8" )` it produced "9CC2E0D1D41E67BE9C2AB4AABDB6FD3" (and the length of the byte array became 332). Again, not the result you are looking for.

So, I guess Suomen Verkkomaksut does some massaging of the `prehash` string that they did not document, or you have overlooked.

Comment: Your hash function doesn't pad with zero if byte is less than 10.

Comment: Ah well, maybe I'll just have to wait for an answer from them. Thanks for the provided code example.

Comment: @BalusC. You are quite right. I've corrected my example. Always beats me why Java does not have Byte.toHexString and Byte.toUpperHexString that does the correct thing.

Comment: Simply use the Hex class of apache commons codec which does exactly that. I had to rebuild a HUGE amount of hashes because i used my own, and broken, implementation for byte[] to String conversion.

Answer (score 9):

You seem to misunderstand how string encoding works, and your `Crypt` class's API is suspect.

Strings don't really "have an encoding" - an encoding is what you use to convert between Strings and bytes.

Java Strings are internally stored as UTF-16, but that does not really matter, as MD5 works on bytes, not Strings. Your `Crypt.md5sum()` method has to convert the Strings it's passed to bytes first - what encoding does it use to do that? That's probably the source of your problem.

Your example code is pretty nonsensical as the only effect this line has:

```
String prehashIso = new String(prehash.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "ISO-8859-1");
```

is to replace characters that cannot be represented in ISO-8859-1 with question marks.

Comment: +1 on the suspicious-ness of the `Crypt` class. It also suggests there may be a confusion between encryption and cryptographic hashing (but there may as well not be one, depending on the rest of the class).

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you solved your problem, but I had a similar problem with ISO-8859-1 encoded strings with nordic ä & ö characters and calculating a SHA-256 hash to compare with stuff in documentation. The following snippet worked for me:

```
import java.security.MessageDigest;
//imports omitted

@Test
public void test() throws ProcessingException{
String test = "iamastringwithäöchars";           
System.out.println(this.digest(test));      
}

public String digest(String data) throws ProcessingException {
    MessageDigest hash = null;

    try{
        hash = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    }
    catch(Throwable throwable){
        throw new ProcessingException(throwable);
    }
    byte[] digested = null;
    try {
        digested = hash.digest(data.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String ret = BinaryUtils.BinToHexString(digested);
    return ret;
}
```

To transform bytes to hex string there are many options, including the apache commons codec Hex class mentioned in this thread.

Answer (score 1):

If you send UTF-8 encoded data that they treat as ISO-8859-1 then that could be the source of your problem. I suggest you either send the data in ISO-8859-1 or try to communicate to Suomen Verkkomaksut that you're sending UTF-8. In a http-based protocol you do this by adding charset=utf-8 to Content-Type in the HTTP header.

A way to rule out some issues would be to try a prehash String that only contains characters that are encoded the same in UTF-8 and ISO-8859-1. From what I can see you can achieve this by removing all "ä" characters in the string you'e used.

Comment: I already have both <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> and <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> on the page. Unfortunately these don't seem to help. But you're right, maybe I should just contact them.